# Using a method within another method of the same class in Java

Tags: java, class, methods, nested

I have a class `IPAddressString` that has:

- a `private` field of type `String` called `ipAddress`
- a `public` method `getOctet` with a single argument `int index` that returns an `int`. The return value is computed based on `ipAddress` and `index`
- a `public` method `isPrivateNetwork` that returns a `boolean` based on the return value of `getOctet`

So this is the code:

```java
public class IPAddressString {

    private String ipAddress;

    public IPAddressString(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4) {
        this.ipAddress = num1 + "." + num2 + "." + num3 + "." + num4;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.IpAdress;
    }

    public boolean equals(IPAddressString other) {
        return ((other.toString()).equals(ipAddress));
    }

    public int getOctet(int index) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        int point = index;
        int countPoints = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= ipAddress.length() - 1; i++) {
            if ((ipAddress.charAt(i)) == '.') {
                countPoints++;

            }
            if ((countPoints == point) && ipAddress.charAt(i) != '.') {
                buf.append(ipAddress.charAt(i));
            }

        }
        String result = buf.toString();
        return Integer.parseInt(result);
    }

    public boolean isPrivateNetwork(){
        // I want to use getOctet here
    }

}
```

What I would like to do inside `isPrivateNetwork` is something like `ipAddress.getOctet(someIndex)`, which is not possible because `ipAddress` is a `String` and not an `IPAddressString`. So, on which instance of `IPAddressString` am I supposed to call `isPrivateNetwork`?

Comment: Its difficult to keep all this in the short time memory. Can you provide any code?

Comment: At all not clear. Paste some code. Talking about meaningful names instead of Method1 and Method2 usually helps, too

Comment: It is not clear I am afraid. :)

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like it's reinventing the [`java.net.Inet4Address`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Inet4Address.html) class and its `isSiteLocalAddress` function.

Comment: @R:I'm not familiar with the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So why don't you just use:

```
public boolean isPrivateNetwork(){
    int result = getOctet(yourIndex)
}
```

Comment: getOctet is a method for IPAddressString type, I'm writing a new class,
You can use this way: Nir.getOctet(4); when Nir is an IPAddressString type. Is there something that I miss?

Comment: Yes but your isPrivateNetwork method is in the same class. So you could also use this.getOctet(yourIndex) but this isn't a difference.

Comment: oh, I see and it is automaticly will use the IpAdress that I work with throught the class.Sorry! I Haven't thought about that, I'm a beginner. Thank you.

Comment: No problem we all started this way ;=)